# C# UWP setting textbox's caret foreground color

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp, styles, caret

Does anyone know how to change foreground color of textbox's caret (blinking text cursor) in C# UWP?

[image]

In the WPF there is a property CaretBrush, but in UWP there is no.

I have tried to change textbox style, but can't find that element.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no CaretBrush property or other property about Caret in UWP. It seems it is not supported.